# How to calculate Grand Totals for invoices with multiple purchases in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

One of the queries for the assignment I am working on is: "Create a query that calculates the total dollar amount of the purchase and shows the customer id and customer name related to that purchase for each order." I created all the tables necessary for the assignment and completed the first 2 queries no problem. But for this third query I was able to calculate the total of each individual PURCHASE but couldn't get it to give me the total of each of the purchases in the ORDER cause when I used a `SUM` in front of the price calculation it gave me "not a single-group group function" or when I tried to use `GROUP BY` it said "not a `GROUP BY` function".

I used this Code:

```
SELECT (i.ItemPrice * t.ItemQty) AS Purchase_Total, o.OrderID, c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
FROM pillmanb1_Orders o, pillmanb1_Items i, pillmanb1_Transactions t, pillmanb1_Customers c
WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
AND i.ItemID = t.ItemID
AND o.OrderID = t.OrderID;
```

To get this answer:

[First Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQN04.png)

But what I really need is this:

[Correct Prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80ZoI.png)

I know this one might be easy for you guys but I appreciate the help!!
Thanks!!

Comment: Please show us how did you try to use `sum` and `group by` so that we could give some really useful hints.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) to achieve this

to get grand total:
`sum(i.ItemPrice * t.ItemQty) over () as Grand_Purchase_Total`

to get subtotal by orders:
`sum(i.ItemPrice * t.ItemQty) over (partition by o.OrderID) as Grand_Order_Total`

```
SELECT distinct (i.ItemPrice * t.ItemQty) AS Purchase_Total
  , sum(i.ItemPrice * t.ItemQty) over () as Grand_Purchase_Total
  , sum(i.ItemPrice * t.ItemQty) over (partition by o.OrderID) as Grand_Order_Total
  , o.OrderID, c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
FROM pillmanb1_Orders o
   , pillmanb1_Items i
   , pillmanb1_Transactions t
   , pillmanb1_Customers c
WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
AND i.ItemID = t.ItemID
AND o.OrderID = t.OrderID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I couldn't get it to show the data exactly how I wanted it to show (still pulls 17 results when I want it narrowed down to the 6 like my prediction above). But thanks for showing me how to get the totals!! Any idea on how to minimize the results to just show the order and not each purchase within the order?

Comment: if you remove `(i.ItemPrice * t.ItemQty) AS Purchase_Total` from the query you will have unique OrderId, Cutomser ID and Name and Totals... I think it will be these 6 records

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot! This is what I used to solve the problem! SELECT DISTINCT sum(i.ItemPrice * t.ItemQty) over (partition by o.OrderID) AS Grand_Order_Total
, o.OrderID, c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
FROM pillmanb1_Orders o
, pillmanb1_Items i
, pillmanb1_Transactions t
, pillmanb1_Customers c
WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
AND i.ItemID = t.ItemID
AND o.OrderID = t.OrderID;